# Does anyone know if there is a way to import the google form page as FormPage in WL?

Tags: formpage

Is there a way I can import a google form into wolfram language as a `FormPage`? Is Wolfram's form language complete and can represent every element of google form? Has anyone written functionality that can achieve this?

Or as a simpler thing can I import the form data in some easy to parse way like below:

> <|    {question1Text,...} -> {options,...},    {question2Text,...} ->
> {options,...}    ... |>

Comment: I am not familiar with a Google form. Can you share an example, or point to one?

Comment: @MarcoB Here is an example one: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScJCYDMZB9jAAmlO5OIx740nWg3WrVDrkb9nL8XF1_BE9b-Vg/viewform

Comment: Do you want to replicate the form or just work with the data? The second is easy because Google Forms can export as CSV and Mathematica can work with CSV with exactly 0 effort

Comment: @b3m2a1 for now I just want all the questions and their allowed options into Mathematica but if there is a way to actually get google form control into Mathematica form controls that would be ideal.

Answer (score 3):

The following will read the content of the form, but not the form itself. I do not know if this is good enough for you

You can get the text of the form in one single string by:

```
ue = URLExecute[
  "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/\
1FAIpQLScJCYDMZB9jAAmlO5OIx740nWg3WrVDrkb9nL8XF1_BE9b-Vg/viewform"]
```

The beginning of the string looks like:

```
"Tech Camp Application
In order to receive $250 ....."
```

The same can also be achieved by:

```
Import["https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/\
1FAIpQLScJCYDMZB9jAAmlO5OIx740nWg3WrVDrkb9nL8XF1_BE9b-Vg/viewform"]
```

To chop this string into different pieces according to the structure of the form you may use:

```
ImportString[ue]
```

This gives:

```
{{"Tech Camp Application"}, {"In order to receive $250 compensation \
for this year's Tech Camp you will have to complete this online \
application. You will be notified if your classes and project were \
accepted for compensation."}, {}, {"* Erforderlich"}, {}, {"First and \
Last Name *"}, {"Please enter your full name"} ... }
```